# C Determine if int is ascii value or not

Tags: c

I have the following:

```
#define SIZE 200 //The number digit limitation

typedef struct _btnode {
    int item;
    struct _btnode* left;
    struct _btnode* right;
} BTNode;   // You should not change the definition of BTNode
```

And I'm supposed to store each of the following numbers and operators to the node above

```
+ 99 * - 88 77 + / 66 - 55 44 33
```

Currently, I scan each character, and store the number to a char array then use atoi to convert it to int, so e.g "99" will give me 99, then I store the int value to the node:

```
(*root)->item =  atoi(tempNum); //tempNum is a char array that contains '9', '9' , '\0'
```

If the character is an operator e.g '+',
I store it directly to the node:

```
(*root)->item = *prefix++;
```

the issue comes when I'm printing my tree recursively, and the operators get printed correctly e.g '+', but it also tries to convert the number to the symbol.. how do I determine if the int is the number and not the int value of the character e.g '+'?

```
void printTree(BTNode* node) {
    
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    printTree(node->left);
  
        printf("%c ", node->item);
    
    printTree(node->right);

}
```

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/ctype.h.0p.html

Comment: [`isdigit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit)?

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, all values from `0` to `127` (inclusive) are valid ASCII values.

Comment: Character values are also numbers, so you need to distinguish actual numbers from characters somehow. If only a limited range of numbers is to be supported, you could encode the other characters as numbers outside that range, for example by adding some big constant to the character values.

Comment: Do not erase your question. Add an answer itself if you feel like documenting it... erasing your question just makes comments and answers look out of place.

Comment: Also, when you edited your question to say you solved it by modifying the struct, then you can't have read the comment in the source code: `// You should not change the definition of BTNode`.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't numbers be edge nodes in the graph?

So if `node->left == NULL` and `node->right == NULL`, wouldn't node represent a number and not an operator?

Answer (score 0):

first of all why don't you just keep it as a char instead of an int?

A possible solution is with bitwise operations
it's pretty ugly but if you don't want to change the struct then you can shift `item` to the left `tempNum <<= 1` and then use the space as a boolean that says if it is a number or not.

```
if (tempNum is a number)
    tempNum &= 1;
```

and then when you use it all you got to do is check if it is a number or not and don't forget to shift it back

EDIT:
I saw the other answer, not all operators will be edge cases, + or - in a start for example which is also in the example you gave